What is the referent of the Simpsons line about 'Edward the Penitent'?
When the Simpsons are watching public access television, we see this scene from 'Marge on the Lam', s5e06:

TROY: Hi, I’m Troy McClure. You might remember me from such telethons as “Out with Gout ‘88” and “Let’s Save Tony Orlando's House.” Folks, do you realize without your support public television can't afford to bring you such award-winning shows as “Edward the Penitent?”
EDWARD: I'm really, really, really sorry.
POPE: I'm afraid sorry doesn't cut it with this pope.
EDWARD: Oh-ho.

Not sure how to render that last noise, or what it means.



I understand the intended point — that public television is terrible — but it looks like a reference to something and I don't know what it is.
Have the writers ever explained this joke?

That noise (and the collar pull) mean "Yikes, I'm in trouble now."

This meek, apologetic basin-haired green-robe wearing novice might have been a nod to Christian Slater's similar character in The Name of The Rose (1986) - and more generally, to the many very serious award-chasing historical dramas that had been popular in the 70s and 80s, but around 1993, may have been going somewhat out of style. I feel like a cinema-wise 1993 audience would see this as a dated and comically one-dimensional low-budget low-effort Name Of The Rose cash-in, that took historical names like "Edward the Confessor" or "Ethelred the Unready" comically literally

@user56reinstatemonica8 that's a good explanation, maybe write an answer.

The joke is also, in my view, that American public television was at the time (and perhaps still is to some extent) unaccountably Anglophilic.  Secondhand British television was a major component of every broadcast day for decades, and at the time that programming would likely have been the only exposure that many Americans had ever had to UK culture, which most viewers clicking past the channel would have found befuddling.  Edward the Penitent is probably an attempt to boil this experience of alienation down to its essence.


Have the writers ever explained this joke?

Probably they haven't because I think for much of the audience, it's self-explanatory.
"Edward the Penitent" is not a real show or real person. It's not a reference to anything specific. It does allude to the epithets of historical figures, like "Alexander the Great" or "Edward the Confessor". The latter was a king of the English and was known as "the Confessor" not because he famously confessed to anything specific, but since he had an image of being "unworldly and pious" (according to Wikipedia).
In general, epithets are not literal. So the main thrust of the joke is that in the case of "Edward the Penitent", his epithet is presented extremely literally: he is kneeling and apologizing in penitence to a pope.
The response of the Pope is based on two things: first, a TV series about a person apologizing and then being forgiven would not be much of a story, so if the Pope said, "That's all right, then", it would be strange. Second, award-winning dramas are often tragic, so it would be reasonable to expect the story of Edward to not end with his apology. The Pope not accepting his apology and Edward's resulting fear allude to the events we can expect to happen later in the fictitious show.

And then there are Sir Robin the Not-Quite-So-Brave-As-Sir-Lancelot  and Sir Not-Appearing-In-This-Film). I can't imagine Monty Python not having been mentioned in the writing room of The Simpsons :)
